# Server for iOS app

Tags: java, ios, json

I'm trying to build a server to handle JSON requests from an iOS application. My question is, is there any example how this can be achieved? What is the easiest and most scalable way to get this done?

I have been experimenting with Ruby on Rails, Django, Play! frameworks, and wanted to know other peoples thoughts. Are there any pitfalls for any of these frameworks? Thanks!

Comment: Please read the FAQ - do some research before asking questions.

Comment: I did google around for this and it led to nothing, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: Try googling your title. Worked for me. No sazz intended :p

Comment: Then I guess you didn't understand the question, because I tried it as well, and it didn't answer it--BEFORE posting here. But after a bit more digging (and some advice from the below answers) I found the following page: http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/12/30/example-of-restful-webservice-with-xml-and-json-using-maven-jaxb-jersey-tomcat-and-curl/ -- I was asking for example sources that show how to configure etc., that page has that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to use servlets in tomcat and to manage the encoding and decoding using Google gson.

But you question was too wide, so you'll have to google a little from now.

Answer (score 2):

This question is likely to be closed as not constructive or 'shopping'. However, I'd recommend that you look at any of the widely-used Java REST development kits. The two at the top of my head are Jersey and CXF.